# Как в ASP .NET Core в контроллере изменить свойство HTML-атрибута?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, controller

Есть страница в формате .cshtml для входа на сайт:

```
<body>
<form method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="mail" placeholder="Введите почту" /><br />
    <p id="mailState" style="font-size: 10px"> </p>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Введите пароль" /><br />
    <p id="passwordState" style="font-size: 10px"> </p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember">Запомнить меня<Br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Войти" disabled />
</form>
```

Она называется SignIn. В контроллере есть соответствующее действие, которое обрабатывает POST-запрос страницы. Я хочу чтобы если у меня в БД не нашёлся объект user с логином и паролем, который я ввёл в форму, то у меня в `<p id="mailState" style="font-size: 10px"> </p>` и в `<p id="passwordState" style="font-size: 10px"> </p>` вводился текст "Неправильные данные". Как это можно сделать?

```
[HttpPost]
public string SignIn(string email, string password)
{
    foreach (var user in db.Users)
    {
        if (user.compareData(email, password))
        {
            return "Ты вошёл, " + user.Name + "!";
        }
    }
    
    // сюда хочу вставить код для вывода в <p 
    // id="passwordState"> информацию о том
    // что у меня неправильный пароль
    
}
```

Тут загвоздка в том, что я не знаю именно того, как правильно передать в страницу информацию о неправильных логине и пароле. Передачу этих данных мне нужно сделать без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: А посмотреть на любой сайт слоганом не вариант?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду, не понял?

Comment: Дело в том что посылка формы на бек не все сайты промышляют. Вам нужно посмотреть как обрабатываются скрипты сайта чтоб было без перезагрузки

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы передать текст того, что комментарий неправильный - достаточно его определить во `ViewBag` под какой-либо переменной. А во `View` в ASP .NET Core в качестве текста того, что комментарий неправильный достать этот текст из `ViewBag`.

Однако перезагрузки страницы мне избежать так и не удалось.